# Facebook AudienceNetwork error

Tags: android, facebook, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

I've implemented AudienceNetwork interstitial ads from facebook(FAN) using their Android SDK.

It works good until  7th or 8th ad is shown. Then, the application crashes and throws android.os.TransactionTooLargeException.

Here is the log:

```
08-25 14:57:37.441: E/JavaBinder(910): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/InputDispatcher(910): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-25 14:57:37.451: E/InputDispatcher(910): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-25 14:57:37.451: E/libprocessgroup(910): failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 28261
08-25 14:57:37.451: I/WindowState(910): WIN DEATH: Window{34e42ccc u0 com.test.test/com.test.test.UnityPlayerActivity}
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/InputDispatcher(910): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
08-25 14:57:37.451: I/WindowState(910): WIN DEATH: Window{3f95474c u0 SurfaceView}
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910): Exception in new application when starting activity com.test.test/com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:854)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1597)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:850)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7540)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:7607)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:481)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2965)
08-25 14:57:37.451: W/ActivityManager(910):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910): Exception thrown launching activities in ProcessRecord{3f10b395 30801:com.test.test/u0a405}
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:854)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1597)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:850)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7540)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:7607)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:481)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2965)
08-25 14:57:37.451: A/ActivityManager(910):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
08-25 14:57:37.451: I/ActivityManager(910): Killing 30801:com.test.test/u0a405 (adj 0): error during init
08-25 14:57:37.461: W/ActivityManager(910): Force removing ActivityRecord{2b621023 u0 com.test.test/com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity t149}: app died, no saved state
```

Any Sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an engineer on the Audience Network. We made a change in version 4.7.0 of the sdk that should prevent this by compressing markup data within the sdk to reduce Intent payload size. To mitigate the affect for older sdk versions we've made some modifications to the payload sent down by the server -- but still strongly recommend upgrading to the newest sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem can be the size of the content which you are call and pass into your view, activity or some other container. 
First of all, you can test it with a smaller content about 100KB to understand the exact problem and then you can search to how to reduce the size of the incoming content.

Comment: Have you read the qustion? I only implemented their SDK and call their interstitial. I personally don't transfer any data. I've googled TransactionTooLargeException and I know this, but my problem is with AudienceNetwork.